# What does 'broad' mean in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It was inevitable, given the conceptual and empirical content of development
>   economics in the mid 1970s, that the early World Development
>   Reports painted with a **broad** brush.

Comment: wide paintbrush (crude lines, versus "fine" brush)

Comment: Here is an explanation: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/paint+with+a+broad+brush

Answer (score 1):

*paint with a broad brush* is an idiomatic expression. The sentence simply says that the early World Development Reports regarded things in general terms without getting deeply into the specifics.

Look [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/paint_with_a_broad_brush) for the details (it has got some very good examples under the quotations section). Here's specifically the part of interest:

> **paint with a broad brush**
> (idiomatic) To describe a class of objects or a kind of phenomenon in general terms, without specific details and without attention to individual variations.

Comment: Guess what, I was in the process of editing the answer while you down-voted it.

Comment: @AlanCarmack - Was there a request for the meaning of the expression" paint with a broad brush" or for the meaning of the adjective "broad" in collocation with the noun "brush"? Can't the latter be looked up in a dictionary to provide a definition in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The idiom having been explained, here's the picture of a broad paintbrush for, as TRomano mentioned, painting crude lines:

[image: 1]

To see why it is [*broad*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/broad), here's the picture of a *fine* (thin in thickness) one for painting small details:

[image: 2]